# Как сделать, чтобы в ComboBox стоял элемент из списка в самом начале?

Tags: c#, wpf

Такая проблема: Мне нужно, чтобы при погрузке страницы в combobox , был выбран элемент к конкретному элементу списка. Вот как выглядит при запуске:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при нажатие на какую-либо кнопку, элемент появляется в combobox.Например нажав кнопку вперед, элемент появится, скриншот снизу:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто подсказать, как исправить такую проблему?

```
<ComboBox Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxStyle1}" x:Name="comboBox"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="168,143,271,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>




public pageCoterie()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            comboBox.DataContext = Connection.ds.Tables["Кружок"].DefaultView;
            comboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Преподаватель";
            if (Connection.ds.Tables["Кружок"].Rows.Count > n)
                FieldsForm_Fill();
          
        }
        public static int n = 0;

        private void FieldsForm_Fill()
        {
            txtCode.Text = Connection.ds.Tables["Кружок"].Rows[n]["Код"].ToString();
            txtName.Text = Connection.ds.Tables["Кружок"].Rows[n]["Название кружка"].ToString();
            comboBox.Text = Connection.ds.Tables["Кружок"].Rows[n]["Преподаватель"].ToString();
            txtCode.IsEnabled = false;
            txtCode.Background = Brushes.Gray;
        }
```

Самое первая строчка это строка с разметки. А дальше идет код c# самой формы.

Comment: Достаточно прибиндить SelectedItem и оно само заоаботает как надо. Ну или если не сработает, закинуть в SelectedItem нулевой элемент коллекции принудительно

Comment: Привязывайтесь к таблице кстати не через DataContext, а через ItemsSource сразу, тогда остальные привязки можно будет без костылей в текущем контексте использовать.

Comment: @aepot, да это тоже помогло. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете попробовать сделать так

```
comboBox.SelectedIndex=0;
```